# unsaved changes? FileSystemProvider in VS Code for the Web

Tags: vscode-extensions

This is incredibly niche, but in case somebody knows I'm wondering if it's possible to get that "unsaved" marker to show in [VS Code for the Web](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web) . I'm writing an extension with a custom FileSystemProvider to communicate with a remote storage service. As multiple people may have access to these files this auto-save behaviour is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out auto save is on by default. Had to add `.vscode/settings.json` in the FilesystemProvider. I'll edit this answer if I find another place to override this default.